# Can someone identify this login screen? It ain't normal Windows 10 screen

Tags: windows-10

This is what comes up on colleague's Windows 10 HP laptop, can anyone identify this as a keylogger or HP bloatware or something else?

[image]

Comment: It certainly wont be a keylogger! They would want to hide not be obvious. It is likely to be something from HP though I would have expected them to have a logo on it. Perhaps you could share the model of the PC & whether this has just started happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like HP Bloatware - I have seen screens similar to this on other HP laptops that utilise HP Security software and other features such as the laptop's fingerprint scanner.

Please see here for a similar scenario where the user enabled the HP settings and changed the logon screen: https://superuser.com/questions/690743/login-screen-changed-in-windows-8

> I use an HP Probook 4440s 64bit laptop with Windows 8 Enterprise installed. There is also a utility called HP Security Tools and I enabled a password protect option from it. Doing that somehow changed the normal Windows 8 lock screen to look something like this:

This was Pawan's solution (in case link becomes broken):

> Okay, found the solution myself. Posting it here for further
>   reference.
>
> Once you activate the Spare Key protection, the Windows Logon checker
>   is added to HP Protect Tools. So disabling the Spare Key doesnt take
>   away the login screen, which is a result of added layer of protection.
>
> To bring back the old, normal login screen, open HP Client Security
>   --> Credentials Manager --> Configure Now
>
> You will first need to remove the Spare Key protection, if any.
>
> Then, click on the "Administration" button on the bottom of the left
>   sidebar. Administration --> Administration Console --> Increase System
>   Security --> Uncheck the "Windows Logon security".
>
> And its done. That was all.

*Sidenote*: If it was a security breach on your computer and the attacker managed to load a custom logon screen, then you have a lot more to worry about than them getting your Windows logon credentials.

Comment: Thanks for this post and reply. I almost reinstalled windows due to this HP bloatware.